# Динамический вектор битсетов

Tags: массивы, вектор, c++

Доброго времени суток!
как создать динамический вектор битсетов?
на следующую конструкцию компилятор жутко ругается

```
std::vector< std::bitset<> > *Matrix = new vector< std::bitset<col> >;
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Для `std::bitset<N>` размер [должен быть известен во время компиляции](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset):

> The class template bitset represents a fixed-size sequence of `N` bits. Bitsets can be manipulated by standard logic operators and converted to and from strings and integers.

- Если вам нужен `bitset` с динамическим размером, то используйте [`boost::dynamic_bitset`.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html)